# CardView not showing on android device (api 21 and below)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-cardview, android-gridview

Hi im creating a home dashboard design at my app with cardviews, the problem is, in api 21 (Android 5.1) the cardview doesnt show. I tried putting hardware acceleration in android manifest but still doesnt work. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f2f9ff"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="385dp"
        android:layout_height="273dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/header_img"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ukssssssss"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="142dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="93dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="UKS TK CENDEKIA HARAPAN"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="102dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="193dp" />

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
        android:layout_width="383dp"
        android:layout_height="293dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:rowCount="2"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="239dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/medicalrecord"

                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Medical Record"

                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/plant" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Nusantara Plants"

                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/healingtherapy" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Healing Therapy"

                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/calendaricon"

                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="What's Going On?"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </GridLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="Indonesia Sehat"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Tried on different android version but it works, and also when in the design view i change it into api 21 it also shows a black cardview instead of a white one. Th question on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043607/android-cardview-doesnt-work-on-api-21)doesnt solve my problem, they are asking to solve card elevation, not cardview **not** showing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android CardView doesn't work on Api 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043607/android-cardview-doesnt-work-on-api-21)

Comment: please look at my edit, thanks, and btw it doesnt solve my problem @VishvaDave

Comment: What do you mean by card not showing.. you can not see any card if there is no elevation.. it will be shown as normal layout.. so basically your card is working but shadow is not there so it looks like a normal one.. so try this solution once

Comment: i added elevation in the cardviews @VishvaDave

Comment: see my answer @TimothyDillan

Comment: Elevation would not work in less then 21 api so need to add this attribute mentioned in answer.. why don't you try it once and see the output... also add card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"

Comment: @Timothy Have you managed to solve your problem? An image that I am trying to show inside of a CardView doesn't show up on Android 5.0. None of answers addresses the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First add in Gradle build file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
```

Then change **Grid Layout** to `androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout`
and some required must be changed from *android:* to *app:*

Answer (score 0):

Dude Nothing to do with your code simple add gradle library

Add below library in your Gradle(app) :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.+'
```

- Simply i'll copy your code and paste in my Android Studio. After that i'll add above library and it's give me a below Output :

[image]

Comment: i did lel @MohammadAli

Comment: sry i didn't getting you @TimothyDillan

Comment: i did implement it @MohammadAli

Comment: See in my answer it's giving me a output successfully after adding library

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains such properties of CardView which are compatible with API 22 and above. Due to that reason, CardView cannot be showing.

This is those properties of CarView.

```
android:layout_columnWeight="1"
android:layout_rowWeight="1"
```

You should check on this part.

Comment: so should i delete it? @ParthPatel

Comment: Not like that, but you can try another way.

Comment: what other way is the thing im asking @ParthPatel

Answer (score 0):

put android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in MainFest

Answer (score 0):

These two properties will be showed if CardView resides in GridLayout.

```
<GridLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:rowCount="3"
       android:columnCount="2"
       android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
       android:columnOrderPreserved="false">

               <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:elevation="6dp"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
                        app:cardElevation="6dp"
                        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                        >



            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and this is how I resolved it.

- Step 1: Add android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout to app gradle.
- Step 2: Use android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout instead of GridLayout
- Step 3: Change the following attributes in Gridlayout

```
android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
android:columnCount="2"
android:rowCount="2"
```

To:

```
app:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
app:columnCount="2"
app:rowCount="2"
```

- Step 4: Change the following attributes in Cardview

```
android:layout_rowWeight="1" 
android:layout_columnWeight="1"
```

To:

```
app:layout_rowWeight="1"
app:layout_columnWeight="1"
```

Answer (score -1):

try
using `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` instead `GridLayout` and change

```
android:layout_columnWeight="1"
android:layout_rowWeight="1"
```

properties inside the cardview
to

```
app:layout_columnWeight="1"
app:layout_rowWeight="1"
```